# How to check Object existence in ListModel

Tags: qt, qml, contains, listmodel

I want to add object dynamically to the ListModel.
But I need to append the object only if it does not exist in the model.

I gone through the [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) I couldn't find any methods for this.
Is there any other ways to check this

Comment: You can loop over the `ListModel`. However it is not designed for that. You should consider implementing some kind of `SetModel` yourself in C++.

Comment: You can relate to `ListModel` as array of elements with [ListModel.count](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#count-prop) and [ListModel.get()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method)

Answer (score 0):

The ListModel method get(index) enables you to access each element. It also has a property count, which tells you how many elements are in it.  So, something like this:

```
function appendIfNotExist(objectToAppend) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myListModel.count; i++) {
        if (myListModel.get(i) == objectToAppend) {
            return
        }
    }
    ListModel.append(objectToAppend)
}
```